# opencv python converting frame to gray and writing to new video doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.1.0.4 and Python 3.6 and I am trying to read a video, convert each frame to gray and write it to a new video. This is my code:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
length = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

size = (
  int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
  int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
)

codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('videofile_masked1.avi', codec, 15.0, size)

while(True):
   # Capture frame-by-frame
   ret, frame = capture.read()
   if frame is None:
     break

   frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   output.write(frame)

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run this code, I get this error: 
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in ipp_cvtColor

It works fine when I don't convert the frame to gray!

Comment: It looks like the input frame does not have shape expected. Try checking the number of channels on such frame.

Could it be that the video is already a one channel set of images?

Comment: @PabloDuque I printed out frame.shape and the result is (128, 128, 3), so it has 3 channels, not 1.

Comment: Try adding the check:

if ret:
    #yourcode

Comment: @PabloDuque ret returns true. Like I said, it works fine without converting the frame to gray

Comment: Yes, it is failing the cvtColor call because the input is not right. Try checking the dtype of the frame

Comment: Please, do not write answers as part of your question -- post an actual answer. Furthermore, do not add "Solved" to your questions title -- accepting the appropriate answer from those available (and upvoting it) does the job well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seem simply related to the fact you have keep the last parameter of `VideoWriter` to its default value.

The constructor you are using have this signature:

```
VideoWriter (const String &filename, int fourcc, double fps, Size frameSize, bool isColor=true)
```

Put the last parameter to `false` should fix your issues.